# Analog Clock does not appear in the application

Tags: java, android, android-layout, widget

I'm trying to set a analog clock for my app but both the analog clock and the digital clock just dont appear when i run the app on my device, but if i look at the graphic view of the layout its there!

Heres my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            //Some Text Views and Edit Texts here!


        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="20" >

        <Space
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="2dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="Send"
            android:id="@+id/bSendEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="50" >

        <Space
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="2dp" />
        <AnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/acClock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: move this to Android stack forums

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your layout is not scaling well to varied resolutions. Click the `Preview All Screens` option (in in the Graphical Layout section of Eclipse) to see if you can see the same cropping problem there. If so, you'll need to experiment with different layout weights, etc. to ensure that the layout works well across different device resolutions.

Comment: Thanks! i've tried that and it seems perfect on all devices on the Graphical Layout but on the phone it just does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem can be about ScrollView. Try to change it and let me know result. Because I don't know for which reason its happening but sometimes with ScrollView view is getting hidden...

Comment: I want a analog clock for this application, and i already tried the digital and it just does not work.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to make for it java class or add somethings to your MainClass, try this link, I hope it will be helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQ2W2eoXwro

Comment: Thanks i'm gonna try and will post results.